# python re.compile match percent sign %

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a simple string match for a % sign in Python.
Here is my code

```
import re  
a = "5%"  
p = re.compile(r'%')  
p.match(a)
```

p.match(a) returns None.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`match` matches the regexp if it occurs at the *beginning* of the search string. You want `p.search(a)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `re.match` method only matches patterns if they are at the beginning of the string.  Yours is not.  Try `re.search`, it finds the pattern anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another style:

```
for cell in row:
    cell_val = cell.value
    if bool(re.search(r'% grade', cell_val)):
        print("Yup, found it")
```